# Making n unique l long 0-1 series in Python

Tags: python, list, function, random, unique

I would like to make n random l long 0-1 series, so that all of them are different. I tried to make them with while loop, but it is quite inefficent. I am wondering if there is a better way to do it. (I wrote a separate function which gives back 1 l long 0-1 series and I used it in my other function.)

```py
import numpy as np
alph=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' ', '!', ',', '-', '.', ':', '?', ';','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
class Error(Exception): 
    def __init__(self, text , data):
        self.text = text 
        self.data = data
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.text)+str(self.data)
def key_gen(l):
    a = np.random.randint(2, size=(l))
    return ''.join([str(i) for i in a])
def dict_gen(k):
    if 2**k < len(alph):
        raise Error("There is not enough 0/1 series, can not assign different series to different letters, k is too small:", k)
    else:
        letter={}
        for i in alph:
            for j in alph:
                letter[i]=key_gen(k)
                while key[i]==key[j]:
                    letter[i]=key_gen(k)
      
        return letter
```

For example 3 long 1-0 series: 010, 100, 111....
I would like to a make a dictionary like this, without the while loop I sometimes I get same values to different keys. I would be grateful if you could help me correct my code.

Comment: What do you mean by a 0-1 series? Can you give an example?

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far and why you think it's inefficient? Also, what's the 'I' that keeps popping up here and there?

Comment: @Avian I updated my question.

Comment: @navneethc I updated my question.'l' is just a random letter like 'n' that could refer to any integer, it is the length of the random generated 0-1 series.

Comment: Why are you working at the bit level?  If you want binary sequences of length 3, why not generate integers in the range 0 through 7?  That would also be much easier to insure uniqueness by using a set to reject duplicates, or by shuffling the entire range and picking off the desired number of elements sequentially.  Once you convert your problem to its integer equivalent, you can easily find good existing solutions here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is very obscure and does not depict your overall problem.

What is the purpose of `alph`? Is is only that `n=len(alph)`, but even this is not clear since right now you run a double loop of length `nxn`. So who many unique sequence do you want to create?

Also for sequences of length 3 there are only 7 (2^3-1), but len(alph) is much much longer than that. So your code should raise an exception for your example "There is not enough 0/1 series, can not assign different series to different letters, k is too small: 3"

Another problem in the code you show is that `key[]` is not defined. Do you mean `letter[]`?

And maybe the main problem: you run a double loop over i, j. But you save the result only in a map according to key `i`.

If I had to guess what you want to do, is to generate an automatic code/encoding of the letter in `alph` to some kind of unique 0-1 code (Note, those code sequences must be longer than 3, more like `int(math.log2(len(alph))) + 1`). If I speculate right your `else` branch should basically be:

```
        letter={}
        for i in alph:
          newseq = key_gen(k)
          while newseq in letters.values():
            newseq = key_gen(k)
          letter[i] = newseq
        return letter
```

But if I continue to speculate, an actual efficient method would be:

```
def dict_gen(alph):
  codes = list(range(len(alph)))
  # now scramble
  n_scramble = len(alph) * 5 # choose
  rngs = np.random.randint(len(alph), size=(n_scramble,2))
  for r in rngs: 
    codes[r[0]], codes[r[1]] = codes[r[1]], codes[r[0]]
  length = int(math.log2(len(alph))) + 1
  fmt = '{{0:0{}b}}'.format(length)
  letters = { c: fmt.format(codes[i]) for i,c in enumerate(alph) }
  return letters
```